# How can I get the shared Link via API in Box.net

Tags: java, authentication, box-api

I used the `get_account_tree` parameter and looped trough the output to get the value of the shared_Link value. However, it does not work. I also used `get_collaboration_link` but no success. How can I store the `shared_Link` to the box.net?

Comment: it would be helpful to show some code, and specify what happens when you say "it does not work"

Answer (score 0):

Information on how to create a shared link is [found here](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file). A sample cURL request looks like:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID \
-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN" \
-d '{"shared_link": {"access": "open"}}' \
-X PUT
```